# add element in a specified height jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to add a special div when the height of an element equal to 500 & 1000 & 1500, i've tried this but it's not working.

```js
var containerDiv = $('#someElement');
if(containerDiv.height() == 500 || containerDiv.height() == 1000 || containerDiv.height() == 1500) {
  $('<p>Test</p>').appendTo(containerDiv);
}
```

`
the problem is that containerDiv.height()  return the hole height but  i want traverse the height

Comment: `while` means that it will do alot of times Do you want just once

Comment: insert a `break` statement at the end of your while loop to break the loop.

Comment: i want to insert 3 div in the specified height

Answer (score 0):

You should add an event listener on div resize, try this code

```
containerDiv[0].addEventListener('resize', function () {
    $('<p>Test</p>').appendTo(containerDiv);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want ?

```
var containerDiv = $('#someElement');
switch (containerDiv.height()) {
  case 500:
    $('<p>Test 500</p>').appendTo(containerDiv);
    break;
  case 1000:
    $('<p>Test 1000</p>').appendTo(containerDiv);
    break;
  case 1500:
    $('<p>Test 1500</p>').appendTo(containerDiv);
    break;
}
```

Comment: it's not doing anything